# How to combine arrays only if they have a common value?

Tags: python

I have a number of pairs of values (pairs of bonded atoms) for a file containing different molecules. If two pairs have a common member, it means that they are part of the same molecule. I am trying to find an efficient way in python to group the atoms depending on which molecule they belong to.

**As an example, ethane and methane would be:**

`1,5` and `9` would be carbon, the rest hydrogen

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[5,6],[5,7],[5,8],[9,10],[9,11],[9,12],[9,13]]
```

And I would like to get a list/array in which I have:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13]]
```

I have tried several things but they are really ineficient for files with a large number of atoms. There should be a smart way of doing it but I can't find it. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Joan

Comment: Do you mean that for any one of the two values? Wouldn't that bind all of the pairs? Does it matter if it is the first or second index? Do you want the final lists to include pairs of values? It is not clear from your example.

Comment: can you give another example i can not understand what you want to do??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you're trying to do is to identify connected components of the graph, where each node is an atom and each edge is a bond (hence, one connected component is a molecule). There is an efficient implementation for this in [`scipy.sparse.csgraph`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.csgraph.html).

So first let's set up the graph as a sparse matrix:

```
import scipy.sparse as sps

# Input as provided
edges = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[5,6],[5,7],[5,8],[9,10],[9,11],[9,12],[9,13]]
# Modify the input by adding, for each [x,y], also [y,x].
# Also transform it to a set and then again to a list
# to assure that we don't duplicate anything.
edges = list({(x[0],x[1]) for x in edges}.union({(x[1],x[0]) for x in edges}))
# Create it as a matrix. The weights of all edges are set to 1,
# as they don't matter anyway.
graph = sps.csr_matrix(([1]*len(edges), np.array(edges).T))
```

At this point, it's just a matter of calling [`scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components.html#scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components), but the output has a slightly different format by default:

> (3, array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]))

So let's modify it a bit:

```
from scipy.sparse import csgraph
connected_components = csgraph.connected_components(graph)
result = []

for u in range(1, connected_components[0]):
    result.append(np.where(connected_components[1]==u)[0])

result
```

> [array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int64),
>
> array([ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], dtype=int64)]

Also remark that in `range` I've started from 1, because Python standard counts from 0 and this would be found as an isolated node since you start from 1. If the numbering of the atoms is non-continuous, the one needs to skip the isolated nodes, for example by doing:

```
result = [r for r in result if len(r) > 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bigArr = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[5,6],[5,7],[5,8],[9,10],[9,11],[9,12],[9,13]] ## Your list of pairs of values
molArr = []
for pair in bigArr:
    flag = False
    for molecule in molArr:
        if pair[0] in molecule or pair[1] in molecule: ## Add both values if any of them are in the molecules list
            molecule.append(pair[0])
            molecule.append(pair[1])
            flag = True ## The values have been added to an existing list

    if not flag: ## The values weren't in an existing list so add them both
        molArr.append(pair)

i = 0
for i in range(len(molArr)): ## Remove duplicates in one loop
    molArr[i] = list(set(molArr[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
a = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[5,6],[5,7],[5,8],[9,10],[9,11],[9,12],[9,13]]

result = []

for sub in a:
    join = False
    for i, r in enumerate(result):
        if any([x in r for x in sub]):
            join = True
            index = i
    if join:
        result[index] += [y for y in sub if y not in result[index]]
    else:
        result.append(sub)

result
#[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13]]
```